# How to get the index of the maximum element in an array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to find the maximum value in an array and print his index.

I wrote this for print the maximum value; it works but I don't know how print the index.

```
use feature "say";
use List::Util qw(max);
@x=qw(10 -2 -48 -5 7 34 28);
say "valore massimo: ".max @x;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small task such as this, you don't really need to use external libraries.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @x = (10, -2, -48, -5, 7, 34, 28);
my $max = 0;     # first index is the max
for (0 .. $#x) {
    if ($x[$_] > $x[$max]) {
        $max = $_;
    }
}
say "@x";
say "Max number is $x[$max] with index $max";
```

Output:

```
10 -2 -48 -5 7 34 28
Max number is 34 with index 5
```

Just loop over the indexes, check the values and save the index with the highest number.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it works great. I ask you another detail, if i want find the maximum negative value (-2) and his index, is it possible with this code?

Comment: @MauroConsole Of course, you can just swap the comparison around, from `>` to `<`.  You're welcome

Comment: maybe I expressed myself wrong, I would like to find in this example (-2,) which is the biggest negative value and its index is it possible modify this code to achieve this?

Comment: @MauroConsole Yes, you just have to tweak the comparisons. In your case you want it to be `<0` and highest, so just set it to skip if >=0, e.g. `next if $x[$_] >= 0`. That works for every number, not just negative.

Comment: i tried to use next if $x[$_] >= 0 between   if ($x[$_] > $x[$max]) {    and  $max = $_; but doesn't work. is it  the correct position and is it write in the correct way? @TLP

Comment: @MauroConsole You should put it right after the loop condition `for`, and before the `if`.

Comment: I had already tried it Inserting it in that position gives me in output : Max number is 10 with index 0. There is an error that i don't understand @TLP

Comment: I noticed that if in the array the first number is negative the code works, but if it is positive as in this case (10) it doesn't work

Comment: @MauroConsole Yes, perhaps I should avoid answering questions on the fly. In this case I forgot that we started with index 0. But at least you got some practice debugging.

Comment: what do you advise me to change in the code?

Comment: @MauroConsole You would have to change the initialization of the $max variable. Considering the things we have talked about, an alternative would be to leave it undefined, and inside the loop first have the `next if ...` and after that use `$max //= $_`, using the defined-or assignment operator. It is the equivalent of `$max = $max // $_`. If $max is defined, it will do nothing, hence it will only work the first time. Just leave `my $max;` at the start.

Comment: @MauroConsole You should also know that asking follow-up questions with new requirements can be frowned upon, especially when it involves more thinking and testing. The best option then is to solve the details on your own, or failing that, ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

The core [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#reduce) comes with an almighty `reduce`, which can be used to direclty work out all kinds of results

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw(reduce);

my @x = qw(10 -2 -48 -5 7 34 28);

my $max_idx = reduce { $x[$a] > $x[$b] ? $a : $b } 0..$#x;

say "Maximal value of $x[$max_idx] is at index $max_idx";
```

Can wrap this in a simple function, to have a clear name for the operation (`max_idx` or something, and which can return both the element and its index, perhaps only in list context).  Libraries for list utilities often merely package `reduce` expressions into handy functions.

A utility with the above functionality is `max_by` from [List::UtilsBy](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy), as shown in [Silvio Mayolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73268981/4653379) (but we don't have to make an array of indices first).

---

A nitpick but I 'd like to mention.  The list of (obviously) numbers given in the question as `qw(10 -2 -48 -5 7 34 28)` is a list of strings ("words"), as [qw operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qw/STRING/) builds things.

These are treated as numbers once they are used that way, as normally done by the interpreter, and all is well.  However, since they are clearly to be numbers I prefer to introduce them as such

```
my @x = (10, -2, -48, -5, 7, 34, 28);
```

A touch more typing but I find that it conveys the intent more clearly.  Again, by all means this is of no consequence for most (any?) code.

Answer (score 1):

[`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) provides the [`max_by`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy#max_by), for getting a maximum according to some other criterion (which could be another list).

```
use 5.010;
use List::UtilsBy qw/max_by/;

my @x = qw(10 -2 -48 -5 7 34 28);
my @indices = (0..@x-1);
say max_by { $x[$_] } @indices;
```

Generally, if you're doing nontrivial list manipulation in Perl, I recommend installing [`List::AllUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::AllUtils), which is an all-in-one package including `List::Util`, `List::SomeUtils`, and `List::UtilsBy`.

Comment: using that give me an error. is there an other way without using List::UtilsBy qw/max_by/?

Comment: Not with `List::Util`. You can always do it with a straight-up loop, but given that you're already using external libraries, I assumed you were trying to avoid that.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo List::Util is a core library in Perl.

Comment: @TLP Hm... so it is. Was it always a core library? I'm either remembering an old version of Perl or just completely misremembering then. My mistake.

Comment: Also, do you really need to create a new array that holds the indexes to the first array? I.e. compare with `max_by { ... } 0 .. $#x`.

Comment: `>corelist List::Util

Data for 2020-07-17
List::Util was first released with perl v5.7.3`

Answer (score 0):

The task you are doing is absolutely basic and crucial to programming. If you start to learn programming, you should be able to come up with a solution on your own.

Yes, there exists nice modules that make this task a lot more elegant, but if you are learning to programming, you should come up at least with a solution like this, ON YOUR OWN!

```perl
printf "%d\n", max_index(10,3,22,5,4,11,33); # prints 6
printf "%s\n", max_index(34,21,100,12,9);    # prints 2

sub max_index {
    my ( @list ) = @_;
    
    my $max_index = 0;
    my $max_value = shift @list;
    
    my $idx = 0;
    for my $current ( @list ) {
        $idx++;
        if ( $current > $max_value ) {
            $max_index = $idx;
            $max_value = $current;
        }
    }
    
    return $max_index;
}
```

Homework:

1. What happens if you pass no element to the function? What should be returned?
2. Make it work with an array reference.
3. Use a classic for-loop `for (..., ..., ...) { ... }`, and don't use `shift`.
4. What happens if you pass strings to it, instead of numbers?
5. Do you know a solution to problem 4?

Answer (score 0):

In situation if you would prefer to use only Perl due restriction on Perl module installation - to find index of maximum value in an array you could use following algorithm:

- assume that first element in the array has `$max` value
- compare following array elements with `$max`
- store index and value for max element if satisfices the condition

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @arr = qw(10 -2 -48 -5 7 34 28);
my($ind,$max) = find_max(\@arr);

say "arr[$ind] = $max";

sub find_max {
    my $arr = shift;

    my($i,$max)=(0,$arr->[0]);
    
    for( 1..$#{$arr} ) {
        ($i,$max) = ($_,$arr->[$_]) if $max < $arr->[$_];
    }
    
    return ($i,$max);
}
```

Output

```
arr[5] = 34
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
use List::Util qw(max);

my @x = qw(10 -2 -48 -5 7 34 28);
my ($index) = ( grep { $x[$_] eq max(@x) } 0..$#x );
print "max ", max(@x), " index $index\n";
```

Output

```
max 34 index 5
```